# Using test and date to compare current hour ro range

Tags: bash, scripting, date, variable, test

I am new to Gnu/Linux and bash, and I am trying, unsuccessfully, to write a simple bash script to test if `date +%H` is within a predefined range of hours.

Example:

```
hour='date +%H'
if [[ $hour -ge 12 ]] || [[ $hour -lt 19 ]]
then echo "Good afternoon!"
```

Trying to isolate a line to this results in "integer expression expected":

```
test $hour -ge 12
```

It feels like I'm missing something simple to either have $hour return as integer or just handle it as a string.

Edit:
Here's the completed script, any necessary improvements on the basic level?

```
!#/bin/bash
name=$(whoami)
hour=$(date +%H)
if [ $hour -lt 5 ] || [ $hour -ge 19 ]
then xmessage -center "Good evening $name!"
elif [ $hour -ge 5 ] && [ $hour -lt 12 ]
then xmessage -center "Good morning $name!"
else xmessage -center "Good afternoon $name!"
fi
```

Comment: You have to be careful with comparing dates: at 8am or 9am, `date +%H` will return `08` or `09` -- and then bash arithmetic will complain about "value too great for base" because those are invalid octal numbers. Use `date +%_H` to get space-padded hours instead of zero-padded hours.

Comment: @glennjackman Or use the non-standard but commonly available `%k` (hour, 0-24).

Comment: With `zsh`: `(){print Good ${argv[2+($1>11)+($1>18)]}.} ${(%):-%D{%H}} morning afternoon evening`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Or `zsh -c 'what you just wrote'` from the `bash` shell...

Comment: Regarding your recent update: Yes, the `#!` at the start of the first line should read nothing but `#!`.  Yours is swapped.  Also, I would quote all variable expansions, and use `printf` to output variable data.  See [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are assigning the literal string `date +%H` to the variable `hour`.

To run that `date` command and to assign the *output* of it to `hour`, use a command substitution:

```
hour=$(date +%H)
```

Alternatively, with a recent release of the `bash` shell (4.2+),

```
printf -v hour '%(%H)T' -1
```

would do the same thing without using `date` at all.

Also, you need `fi` to go with that `if` and use `&&` ("and") in place of `||` ("or") to get the logic correct:

```
if [ "$hour" -ge 12 ] && [ "$hour" -lt 19 ]; then
    echo 'Good afternoon'
fi
```

I'm using the standard `[ ... ]` test rather than the `bash` shell's own `[[ ... ]]` test here to avoid issues with values of `$hour` being interpreted (in an arithmetic context introduced by the `-ge` and `-lt` tests) as invalid octal numbers (`08` and `09`).

If you feel you need to use `[[ ... ]]` you may test `${hour#0}` instead of the unmodified value of `$hour` to avoid issues.  The value of `${hour#0}` will be the same as `$hour` but with any single leading `0` removed.

```
if [[ ${hour#0} -ge 12 && ${hour#0} -lt 19 ]]; then
    echo 'Good afternoon'
fi
```

Comment: Perfect, command substitution and having the incorrect || vs && was the issue. No need for [[ ... ]] specifically vs [ ... ] based on your explanation. I'm working off basic slides from my class and hadn't learned the difference in the two yet and appreciate the extra info!

Answer (score 0):

Bash also supports the `((...))` syntax for arithmetic operations. Your code can be rewritten as:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -i hour=$(date +%k)
if (( hour > 12 && hour < 19 ))
then
    printf "Good afternoon\n"
fi
```

The line `declare -i hour=$(date +%k)` specifies that the variable `hour` is to be treated as an arithmetic integer and assigns the current hour (0-23) to it with no leading zero.